# Zip multiple, specific folders into one zip file

Tags: python, file, zip, directory

I have a bunch of folders full of data and I need specific ones to be sent to a zip folder. I can move them with a batch file but it does not automatically zip and then I have redundancy. I also tried a solution I saw.

```
import os
import zipfile    

def zipit(folders, zip_filename):
    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filename, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

    for folder in folders:
        for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(folder):
            for filename in filenames:
                zip_file.write(
                    os.path.join(dirpath, filename),
                    os.path.relpath(os.path.join(dirpath, filename), 
os.path.join(folders[0], '../..')))

    zip_file.close()


    folders = [
        "\Users\andria.baunee\Desktop\New folder",
        "\Users\andria.baunee\Desktop\New folder (2)",
        "\Users\andria.baunee\Desktop\New folder (3)"]


    zipit(folders, "\Users\andria.baunee\Desktop\hooray.zip")
```

Nothing seemed to happen.